# Doxygen dependencies to manage during install

Tags: installation, doxygen

i am supposed to document my code with doxygen for a homework assignment, but i have problems getting doxygen to run.

I have a Doxyfile provided, and have just installed doxygen on my machine.

When i enter the command to run doxygen, "doxygen Doxyfile" I get the following error:

> failed to run html help compiler on
>   index.hhp

can anyone clue me into what i am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, looks like Microsoft help compiler needs to be installed.